# Typescript type inference on methods doesn't show the proper violet cube icon in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, methods, icons, type-inference

I know this might be an issue just for me (lmao), but this thing is making me crazy! lmao

## Problem

Visual Studio Code infers methods and variables. Notably a little violet square icon appears next to 
 methods:[image] 
and a little blue parallelepiped appears close to 
variables:[image]
It's a pretty simple issue. When creating a class in typescript, if the class inherits from an interface the definition of the methods, VC doesn't show the icons correctly. I may be missing something here, but it's really weird and annoying to be honest!

## Code example

For example, in a simple code like this one:

```
interface Foo {
  do: () => void
}

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.do = function () { console.log("did it") }
  }
}

class Boo {
  do() { console.log("did it") }
}

const foo = new Foo()
const boo = new Boo()
```

There are two basically identical classes, but if you try to access the members in `Foo`, `do` is represented as a variable:

[image]

while `Boo` it shows properly:

[image]

I did a [repl](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyAJugFzIAUAlMgLwB8yAbusMQQL4EEIA2cAM6C0mHASIJ0IQWCgBXBGHRQa4wkWRgAFsEEA6UvWQx5IJcGlVa2ZFJno+EfX3QBzSgCJi7ZMDCetNwawcG8AsLIAEJieBqkarb2go7Orh6eCMBw6IHIoTz4yWAmYnTIIBAA7qLoNLzSssgARmUV1dGYNEA) on ts ide if you want to check the issue!

### Side note

I noticed this happens aswell if, inside the class, the methods are declared as arrow functions :

```
class Some {
....
  do=()=>console.log("did it")
}
```

this code here ^ has the same issue as the one in the repl, it shows methods as variable (parallelepiped) and not as proper methods(violet cube).

## Question

Is there a way to make Visual Studio Code properly interpret the methods as cube icons and variables with parallelepiped ones?

Thanks in advance..
Giacomo

Answer (score 0):

I understood why!! eheh my bad, I was simply using the wrong type of declaration, using arrow functions in the interface will make ts infer the member as an parameter and not as a method!!!

```
interface Foo {
  do: () => void // this one resolves as a parameter icon
  method(): void // this one with a method icon!
}
```

I corrected the code in the ts [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyAJugFzIAUAlMgLwB8yAbusMQUQLYRgAW6YjTKt2BAL4ECCADZwAzvLSYcnZAnQh5YKAFcEYdFBqrCRZP2DyAdKXrIYukAeCaqtbOs3z0MiNZl0AHNKACJidmRgMFDaSTN4%20Ok5RWQAIRU8M1ITTw0tX39AkNCEYDh0WOREqXx87QcVOmQQCAB3ZXQaaW8wZAAjJpb29MwaIA)

=)